# Why does the Flash's speed not affect people or objects?

Tags: analysis, arrowverse, the-flash

In the first season, we see in the opening credits, that when Flash runs, the glass of cars is affected by the Flash's speed.

But neither in the any season nor in any other series where the Flash goes, they show effect of Flash's high speed on any human or things.

How is that possible that an object of speed of mach 2 or 3 passes by you and you don't get thrown or get harmed?

Comment: See SF&F - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69369/why-doesnt-the-flashs-speed-kill-the-people-he-saves

Comment: I got point how people are not affected when he saves them. But when he runs to save other, or passed by some empty street, why object (like car or other house glasses) are still intect?

Comment: Same thing...he can control the Speed Force....it's **comics**. Real physics don't apply.